# Increasing ball (object) speed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have create simple game.  How can I increase the speed of ball. Please help!

> -(void)BallMovement{
>
> ```
>         [self ComputerMovement];
>         [self Collision];
>
>         football.center = CGPointMake(football.center.x + X, football.center.y + Y);
>
>         if (football.center.x < 15) {
>             X = 0 - X;
>         }
>
>         if (football.center.x > 305) {
>             X = 0 - X;
>         }
>
>         if (football.center.y < 0) {
>
>             PlayerScoreNumber = PlayerScoreNumber + 1;
>             PlayerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", PlayerScoreNumber];
>
>             [timer invalidate];
>             StartButton.hidden = NO;
>             button.hidden = NO;
>             football.center = CGPointMake(147, 250);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

clearly based on your code `variable X` is your velocity.

so just increase it. (example X +=0.1) based on some condition.

Comment: Thanks, but it is till not speeding. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try with x=x+3; and add it as first line in that method

Comment: dude , iam asking what is X. you straighforwardly used X in your method like it was a global variable,iam asking about it

Answer (score 0):

> -(void)BallMovement{
>
> ```
>      X=X+1
>
>     [self ComputerMovement];
>     [self Collision];
>
>     football.center = CGPointMake(football.center.x + X, football.center.y + Y);
>
>     if (football.center.x < 15) {
>         X = 0 - X;
>     }
>
>     if (football.center.x > 305) {
>         X = 0 - X;
>     }
>
>     if (football.center.y < 0) {
> ```